# boost::asio::thread_pool iterating over threads

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I have a quite nasty deadlock condition in my application which I know how to solve, but it requires me to get all thread ids in advance, after constructing the boost::asio::thread_pool, and before actually using it.

How can I iterate over all threads in a boost::asio::thread_pool in order to get the thread ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert your threads into the pool:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
using std::ranges::views::transform;

static std::string pretty_id(std::thread::id id) {
    return fmt::format("{:02x}", std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(id) % 0xff);
}
static std::string this_id() { return pretty_id(std::this_thread::get_id()); }

int main() {
    boost::asio::thread_pool pool(0); // empty

    std::vector<std::thread::id> ids;

    for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i) {
        std::thread worker{[&pool] {
            fmt::print("Thread {} attaching\n", this_id());
            pool.attach();
            fmt::print("Thread {} exiting\n", this_id());
        }};

        ids.push_back(worker.get_id());
        worker.detach(); // attach transfers ownership to pool
    }

    fmt::print("Operational: {}\n", ids | transform(pretty_id));

    pool.join();
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e39164577e56427f)**, printing

```
Thread fa attaching
Thread d3 attaching
Thread 82 attaching
Thread a3 attaching
Thread 31 attaching
Thread 35 attaching
Thread 32 attaching
Thread e5 attaching
Thread f0 attaching
Operational: ["fa", "d3", "a3", "31", "82", "35", "32", "e5", "f0", "d6"]
Thread d6 attaching
Thread d6 exiting
Thread fa exiting
Thread d3 exiting
Thread 82 exiting
Thread a3 exiting
Thread e5 exiting
Thread 31 exiting
Thread f0 exiting
Thread 32 exiting
Thread 35 exiting
```

> CAVEAT: the idea of "fixing" deadlocks with bespoke logic based on thread ids sounds like a design smell.

Comment: Thanks! About the deadlock situation I'm facing: I have an event system with a fixed size queue. This fixed size queue forces me to resolve the situation where a consumer thread may try to push an event to the event queue when at full capacity. Decoupling the threads would be another option, but would come with some internal drwabacks.